# Problem with saving data in Join Table in Many to Many relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have problem with saving data in join table in many to many relation. I have 2 model classes:employee and task. When Im assinging new task to employee it is not saving in the employees_task table, only Id of task is changing in choosen employee. [This is how looks table generated by Spring.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRcBr.png)

Im assigning tasks with this method in TaskController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task/assign/{taskId}")
    public String assignTask(@PathVariable("taskId")Integer id, @ModelAttribute Employee employee){
        Task task = tasksService.getTaskById(id);
        employee.addTask(task);
        employeeService.save(employee);
        return "redirect:/employees";
   }
```

Im saving data to database with JPARepository Interface.
Employee class:

```
@Entity(name = "employees")
public class Employee{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String surname;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "employees_tasks",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    )
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    public void addTask(Task task) {
        this.tasks.add(task);
        task.getEmployees().add(this);
    }   


   //constructors,setters,getters 
}
```

Task class:

```
@Entity(name = "tasks")
public class Task{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "task_id")
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int numberOfLeftContractors;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tasks",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "employees_tasks",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    )
    private Set<Task> tasks;

public void addTask(Task task) {
        if(tasks==null) {
            tasks=new HashSet<task>();
        }
        tasks.add(task);
}
```